Automatically display chapter title on the header when no section is started
I like to set the page header to show only the chapter title on the pages where the sections are absent or have not been started.
Here is my MWE. I am doing it by the \markright command.
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}

\title{Conditional header}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Introduction}
\markright{Introduction}
\blindtext[1] \blindtext[1] \blindtext[1]

No section has started, so the chapter title appears in the header. 

\blindtext[1] \blindtext[1] \blindtext[1]

\section{Testing}
It has a section now, so the section title appears in the header.

\end{document}

How can I automate it so that \markright is not needed to call for each chapter with the same condition?

\chaptermark is automatically called by \chapter.  It is passed the title.  It is usually set as part of the page style.
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}

\title{Conditional header}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[1] \blindtext[1] \blindtext[1]

No section has started, so the chapter title appears in the header. 

\blindtext[1] \blindtext[1] \blindtext[1]

\section{Testing}
It has a section now, so the section title appears in the header.

\end{document}


Thank you. It works even if I put \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}} in the preamble. \pagestyle{fancy is not changing it.

Keeping your last line/comment out of the code fences would look better.

Oops.  It was part of a different "answer".
